# Adding markers (bubbles) into simple content slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help with adding markers (bubbles) into simple content slideshow, which will help users to switch between divs.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">

  <div style="background:green;"></div>
  <div style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div style="background:red;"></div>
  <div style="background:grey;"></div>

  // etc

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow { position:absolute; margin:0; width:100%; height:50%; }

#slideshow > div { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

**JS:**

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

 setInterval(function() { 
 $('#slideshow > div:first')
.fadeOut(1000)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hnc92qmb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">

  <div class="slide" id="div1" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="div2" style="background:blue;"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="div3" style="background:red;"></div>
  <div class="slide" id="div4" style="background:grey;"></div>

  // etc
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a data-showdivid="div1"></a></li>
    <li><a data-showdivid="div2"></a></li>
    <li><a data-showdivid="div2"></a></li>
    <li><a data-showdivid="div2"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow {position:relative;)

#nav {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;position:absolute;/*etc*/}
#nav > li {margin:10px;padding:0;display:inline-block;}
#nav > li > a {display:block;width:30px;height:30px;border-radius:15px;background:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this);
    var showDivId= clicked.data('showdivid');
    $('div.slide').not('#' + showDivId).fadeOut();
    // or however you manage the transitions
});
```

**Automatically Add Bubbles**

You can automatically append bubbles using javascript. First add an empty `<ul id="nav"></ul>` into the html. Then on page load, call a function like this:

```
$('#slideshow > div.slide').each(function(){
    var divId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('ul#nav').append('<li><a data-showdivid="'+ divId +'"></a></li>');
});

$('#slideshow').on('click', 'ul#nav > li > a', function(){
    var clicked = $(this);
    var showDivId= clicked.data('showdivid');
    $('div#'+showDivId).fadeIn();
    $('div.slide').not('#' + showDivId).fadeOut();
    // or however you manage the transitions
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h961yskc/

Comment: Yeah.. i did not expected that. Is there any other way to make this simple? I mean, that with your code, everytime  i need to manualy add bubble code..

Comment: See updated answer - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is what i am looking. However, can you look at this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/hnc92qmb/2/ . Its opens last slideshow and bubble works only once.

Comment: See update again.  There may be better ways to handle the transitions, this is pretty basic....

Comment: Thank you. Perfect. One more question.. how to start slideshow from first div, not from last?

Comment: Yeah I pasted the wrong fiddle code in.  Now corrected.

Comment: How about my last question? :)

Comment: Well, then you have to take into account z-indexes and stacking order, and it can start to get pretty complicated (too complicated for my skills) . As a quick fix, you can put the html of the slides into reverse order.  The last one in the html is the "top" slide.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a pager like this:

```
<ul class="pager">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Then you can wire up some javascript events to the `<a>` tags like this:

```
$('#slideshow .pager a').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).parent().index();
    $('#slideshow div').fadeOut();
    $('#slideshow div:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ej44brys/2/).

Comment: Maybe there is a more simple way? Everytime i need manualy add bubble code when new div appears..

Comment: @Tauras I'm not sure what you mean by _i need manualy add bubble code_. That javascript will work with dynamic content, so if you add more or less slides it will still work